# Chakra UI Icons

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9DnX.png)

When I include icons from such as "MoonIcon" or "SunIcon" from '@chakra-ui/icons' I get the classic "Error:Invalid Hook Call".
Im not really sure what this is caused by? This could be some npm/yarn or otherwise a dependency issue, any ideas how to mitigate it?
I am using Chakra UI with the yarn typescript starter setup.

```
import * as React from "react"
import {
  ChakraProvider,
  VStack,
  Code,
  Grid,
  theme,
  useDisclosure,
  useColorModeValue,
  Flex,
  Box,
  Text,
  IconButton,
  Button,
  Stack,
  Collapse,
  Link,
  Popover,
  PopoverTrigger,
  PopoverContent,
  useBreakpointValue,
  Icon,
  useColorMode,
  Menu,
  MenuButton,
  Avatar,
  MenuList,
  Center,
  MenuDivider,
  MenuItem
} from "@chakra-ui/react";

import { ColorModeSwitcher } from "./ColorModeSwitcher"
import { Logo } from "./Logo"
import {
  HamburgerIcon,
  CloseIcon,
  ChevronDownIcon,
  ChevronRightIcon,
  MoonIcon,
  SunIcon,
} from '@chakra-ui/icons';
import Nav from "./Navigation";


function App() {
  const { colorMode, toggleColorMode } = useColorMode();
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();

  return (

    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      {/* <Nav/> */}
      <Box bg={useColorModeValue('gray.100', 'gray.900')} px={4}>
      <Flex h={16} alignItems={'center'} justifyContent={'space-between'}>
          <Box>Logo</Box>

          <Flex alignItems={'center'}>
            <Stack direction={'row'} spacing={7}>
              <Button onClick={toggleColorMode}>
                {colorMode === 'light' ? <MoonIcon /> : <SunIcon />}
              </Button>

              <Menu>
                <MenuButton
                  as={Button}
                  rounded={'full'}
                  variant={'link'}
                  cursor={'pointer'}
                  minW={0}>
                  <Avatar
                    size={'sm'}
                    src={'https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/male/username.svg'}
                  />
                </MenuButton>
                <MenuList alignItems={'center'}>
                  <br />
                  <Center>
                    <Avatar
                      size={'2xl'}
                      src={'https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/male/username.svg'}
                    />
                  </Center>
                  <br />
                  <Center>
                    <p>Username</p>
                  </Center>
                  <br />
                  <MenuDivider />
                  <MenuItem>Your Servers</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem>Account Settings</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem>Logout</MenuItem>
                </MenuList>
              </Menu>
            </Stack>
          </Flex>
        </Flex>
      </Box>
      <Box textAlign="center" fontSize="xl">
        <Grid minH="100vh" p={3}>
          <ColorModeSwitcher justifySelf="flex-end" />
          <VStack spacing={8}>
            <Logo h="40vmin" pointerEvents="none" />
            <Text>
              Edit <Code fontSize="xl">src/App.tsx</Code> and save to reload.
            </Text>
            <Link
              color="teal.500"
              href="https://chakra-ui.com"
              fontSize="2xl"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
            >
              Learn Chakra
            </Link>
          </VStack>
        </Grid>
      </Box>
    </ChakraProvider>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely an issue with Chakra UI package installation, Try reinstalling the package as:

```
npm uninstall @chakra-ui/react @chakra-ui/icons
```

Then

```
npm i @chakra-ui/react @chakra-ui/icons
```

Restart react app

```
npm start
```

Comment: Oh  gosh, thank you very much. You saved me another hour of playing around.